# Storing lots of raw data in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a Rails app which needs to store lots of performance metrics, fed via an API. I'm unable to decide the way to store this data. Since the data will be updated every 10s or so, I don't wish to create ActiveRecord objects.

Are there any alternative ways of storing this type of data?

Comment: How much data will be updated every 10 seconds? If this is one record per 10 seconds then it is a very slow rate and ActiveRecord should be ok.

Comment: @davidrac, going the PostgreSQL way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well 10 seconds per DB transaction is nothing comparing to high scale application, ActiveRecord+PostgreSQL should be ok for your app just configure your PostgreSQL correctly with Vacuum.

i tried once to use Redis for main data store it wasn't a good journey but you can find more info here:

https://muut.com/blog/technology/redis-as-primary-datastore-wtf.html

Answer (score 1):

You should try using Redis or Mongo DB. Redis more simple to use.

Comment: I'd go the redis way but I want persistence. And since I'm stuck with RDBMS here, I'll go postgresql (I should have mentioned). Thanks anyways, @supernini